# Gnome Boxes won't create a VM

Tags: pantheon-terminal, vala, gnome

Running from the GUI I get "Box setup failed" -pretty sparse there Gnome team!! (I know this is the elementary forum, but just saying...)

Running from Terminal, I get:

(gnome-boxes:31127): Boxes-WARNING **: wizard.vala:463: Incapable host system

I'm posting this here because this only happens with elementary OS Loki. VirtualBox works fine...

Ideas?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Boxes, also known as GNOME Boxes is an application of the GNOME Desktop Environment, used to access remote or virtual systems. (wiki)

you should install underlying nessesary tools (in this case qemu)

```
sudo apt install qemu-system
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need KVM to run Boxes. Try this...

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils

sudo adduser  libvirtd

sudo adduser kvm
```

it's what I use in order to run the Android Emulator for testing, it should help with your Boxes issue as well.

you might also want to install `virt-manager`. Run it and you should see QEMU/KVM in the list. This will confirm you're good to go :)

Reference:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Comment: I am not sure that you have to add the users manually, the packages should take care of this.

Comment: You may be right.

Answer (score 0):

recommend use "virt-manager" instead of 'boxes'